# Read from a table while a transaction in going on - Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I am using Oracle9i (9.2). I have a situation where I have to populate a table daily. Daily at mid night this table will be truncated and new data will be put in. The new data population takes about 10-20 mins. The issue is that this table can't be down(locked). While the new data is being inserted, the previous days data needs to be available for a select procedure.

Edit - I am looking into the transaction levels. I just need some expert opinion.

Is this possible in Oracle?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you say the table is truncated and new data inserted. But the table is being used for queries, with the previous days data; but the table is truncated??

Comment: Yea I was hoping truncation or deletion can be done inside a transaction but not committed. Until it is committed, the data in the table should remain in the same status as before the transaction and be available for query. But this is just my assumption.

Comment: TRUNCATE is a DDL command, meaning it's not subject to transaction semantics.

Comment: One way is to `delete * from table` before you populate with the new data; that way the old rows are still available until you `commit`. This will have more overhead than `truncate` but it does satisfy your requirements. It may also make the "update process" longer, but perhaps that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @mathguy That would work, but you would be hurting the query performance (potentially) as you would need to create CR blocks.

Comment: @BobC - Right, I think I even said that myself. The OP should try several solutions and decide what they are most comfortable with.

Comment: Agree with @mathguy.  In many situations, today's data will be very similar to yesterday's data.  When that is true, you can also replace the old data with the new data by inserting, updating, or deleting as needed.  That can save a lot of unneeded deletions and insertions, cut back on UNDO and REDO generated, cut down on consistent read blocks created for queries, etc.  The price is a more complicated refresh process than just delete and reload.

Comment: @mathguy After I read your response,I changed my truncate to delete and ran the new data insert procedure.While this data is being populated by the proc, I queried against this table and I was able to do so. The data which existed in the table was still available while the procedure was running, which is what I wanted. I am not worried about the performance of the new data insertion procedure or the procedure which queries this table because this happens only once every 24 hours, for about 10-20 mins at a low traffic time.The requirement is for the table to be available 'almost' seamlessly.

Comment: I was thinking of this from the sql server perspective with explicit transactions and read levels, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

How about using two tables. Have a "current" table that has the previous days data. Then have a new table which you can load. Then when you are ready, you can "swap" the two tables, using a series of rename operations.

Comment: Use a view which you can swap between the two tables.

Comment: Or `ALTER TABLE...EXCHANGE PARTITION` for super-clean swapping (if you are licensed for partitioning).  That said, I like @mathguy's approach -- delete, insert, commit -- that's the only way I know to keep the data online 100% throughout the entire refresh process.

Comment: Sorry.. noticed the OP is on Oracle 9.2, so `EXCHANGE PARTITION` won't be available for him.

Comment: The swap could also be changing a public synonym to point to tableA vs tableB.  Or even loading into a different schema, but keep same table name, but using public synonym to resolve schema.